# MySQL divide rows an show result on new row

Tags: php, mysql

I am having difficulties with an MySQL query.

The database looks like this:

```
Name   Unit    Int
---------------------
A1     Kilo    20
A1     Price   5
A2     Kilo    15
A2     Price   3
```

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
| Name | Unit  |  int  |
|  A1  | Kilo  |  20   |
|  A1  | Price |  5    |
|  A1  | K/P   |  4    |
|  A2  | Kilo  |  15   |
|  A2  | Price |  3    |
|  A2  | K/P   |  5    |
```

As you can see, I want to insert a new row for every A1 and A2 with a result of Kilo divided by Price.

Is this even possible to do?
If so, could anyone point me in the right direction? I am pretty lost here, and have tried to sweep the internet the last many days, whitout result. I have tried far more ideas than I wish to bore you with.

Comment: Are you hoping to achieve this in php or do it in the query?

Comment: it'll be hard to do so in MySQL better do it in PHP.

Comment: Why don't you have `Kilo` and `Price` as separate tables? You could have a unique `Name` column that you could `JOIN` on. You've made things a bit confusing for yourself here.

Comment: #Epodax - Either way is good for me. I am just hoping to achieve this :)

#jonbladie - Would it be possible to do if I seperated Kilo and Price into two tables? And how so?

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this in your SELECT to calculate it on-the-fly with the latest available data (thus preventing hard-storing something that could later become outdated if the Price/Kilo were to change):

```
SELECT `kilo`.`name`, (`kilo`.`int` / `price`.`int`) AS 'K/P' FROM `stuff` AS `kilo`
LEFT JOIN `stuff` AS `price` ON (`kilo`.`name` = `price`.`name`)
WHERE `kilo`.`unit`='Kilo' AND `price`.`unit`='Price';
```

This would return:

```
+------------+
| name | K/P |
|------------|
| A1   | 4   |
| A2   | 5   |
+------------+
```

And if you'd really want to insert it into your database you could [INSERT ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) the above. Like so:

```
INSERT INTO `stuff` (`name`, `unit`, `int`)
 SELECT `kilo`.`name`, 'K/P', (`kilo`.`int` / `price`.`int`) FROM `stuff` AS `kilo`

LEFT JOIN `stuff` AS `price` ON (`kilo`.`name` = `price`.`name`)
WHERE `kilo`.`unit`='Kilo' AND `price`.`unit`='Price';
```

See the full SQL Fiddle example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cb9f/1).

Comment: #Oldskool - That creates a new column with the result. Is it possible to create a new row with the result?

Comment: @CitronAutobot Yes, use INSERT SELECT in that case, see my latest edit at the bottom.

Comment: Please post the solution here, not just as a sqlfiddle link.

Comment: Posted full solution using INSERT SELECT.

Comment: Yes, yeees yes yes. Now we are talking! But how can I get the result like: Kilo - Price - K/P - Kilo - Price - K/P ? Right now all K/P's are at the bottom.

Comment: @CitronAutobot You can't "pinpoint" inserts in places where you'd like. But you can always sort your select so they're presented together: `ORDER BY name ASC`.

Comment: @CitronAutobot Additional to Oldskool's comment, try `ORDER BY Name, FIELD(Unit,'Kilo','Price','K/P')` with any queries - this will sort your results by Name first, and second by a custom sort order.

Comment: @rosbot + Oldskool - I still haven't been able to do the correct sorting:  Kilo - Price - K/P - Kilo - Price - K/P. It still put K/P in the bottom rows, even though I have tested your ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: @CitronAutobot The query that rostbot posted above works, but Name should be name (lowercase n) and Unit should be unit (lowercase u). Works for me that way.

Comment: @Oldskool
No luck at all. I try this code in the SQL Fiddle: -> 


SELECT `kilo`.`name`, 'K/P', (`kilo`.`int` / `price`.`int`) FROM `stuff` AS `kilo`
LEFT JOIN `stuff` AS `price` ON (`kilo`.`name` = `price`.`name`)
WHERE `kilo`.`unit`='Kilo' AND `price`.`unit`='Price'  
ORDER BY `name`, FIELD('unit','Kilo','Price','K/P');

Comment: Note that `unit` inside the `FIELD` clause should not be a string. See this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1cb9f/11

Answer (score 3):

You can get all results with

```
SELECT * FROM (
    (SELECT * FROM your_table_name)
    UNION
    (SELECT r1.Name as Name, 'K/P', r1.Int/r2.Int
        FROM your_table_name r1, your_table_name r2 
        WHERE r1.Name=r2.Name AND r1.Unit='Kilo' AND r2.Unit='Price'
    )
) AS derived_table
ORDER BY Name, FIELD(Unit,'Kilo','Price','K/P');
```